# How to create sharedpreferences class and use it everywhere in my flutter App

Tags: flutter

How to do it, please give me an idea. It's like a global class which can be accessed by every other class, I actually want to build a util class so that all these things will be only there and I can call these things with just object of util class.

Look this is how I have been doing it

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                      sharedPreferences.setString('uwr_name', ctrUwrName.text);
                      getCredential();
```

And this getCredentail() method I have called where I want data from sharePref.but i don't know Y I need to call it at the time of Setting the data, if I won't put it at the time of setting the data to sharedpref it will give an error

```
getCredential() async {
  sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
```

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).
Then You can create your util class like this,

```
class SessionManager {
  final String auth_token = "auth_token";

//set data into shared preferences like this
  Future<void> setAuthToken(String auth_token) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(this.auth_token, auth_token);
  }

//get value from shared preferences
  Future<String> getAuthToken() async {
    final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String auth_token;
    auth_token = pref.getString(this.auth_token) ?? null;
    return auth_token;
  }
}
```

to set value in setAuthToken method do,

```
 SessionManager prefs =  SessionManager();
 prefs.setAuthToken(welcome.data.auth_token);
```

to get value from getAuthToken method do,

```
 Future<String> authToken = prefs.getAuthToken();
 authToken.then((data) {
 print("authToken " + data.toString());
 },onError: (e) {
     print(e);
 });
```

I have created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/raviganwal/7c2105a2988fc8d69c697f5528cbce26) for your use.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file called `shared_pref.dart`, where in you create a new `SharedPreference` object and all the methods needed (`removeElement, insertElement, etc`).

Then whenever you start your app, you can in the first page, create a SharedPref sp = SharedPref(), and then just pass it around to other pages. However, as SharedPref is saved on in memory, you can just create the object everytime you load a new page.

Comment: Also i want to keep all my sharedPref key in one file

Comment: Well, I guess you could create a list of all the keys. You would need to save it somehow - so if you create a list in that file, and then do getters and setters for that list, you could easily access the keys.

Comment: Hi @Thor, you say " However, as SharedPref is saved on in memory, you can just create the object everytime you load a new page."  So if I load a new page and use ->
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); This won't actually have to wait for SharedPrefs to come from slower memory?  It'll come straight from 'variable memory'?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this library [`shared_preferences`](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). The `shared_preferences` library provide a `SharedPreferences` instance by singleton design pattern which help you connect to XML file on Android or user data on iOS

Answer (score 0):

initialize it on main.dart in main function then use in everywhere like below;

main.dart

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

another page

```
prefs.getString('key');
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing at present, but it means my app is littered with awaits (of course asynced), but I wonder if my app's UI (which is fed by SharedPrefs) being fully functional for the user is thus slowed down compared to other SharedPrefs management.